# PyQt - PySide Custom Widget Won't Show

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to create a custom widget with a button and a label using the code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton('dia', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(100, 20)
```

Following this, I create a class for my main frame and try to display this widget with the code:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.mw = MyWidget()
        self.mw.move(20, 20)

        self.resize(250, 300)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom Widget Example')
        self.show()
```

When I run this script from the terminal, it shows but its blank. I do not see my widget anywhere.

What do I need to do to get this widget showing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using coordinates? Use layouts:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)   #always provide parent!
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton('dia', self)
        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()  #whatever layout you want
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.mw = MyWidget(self)   # remember the parent!
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.mw)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.resize(250, 300)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom Widget Example')
        self.show()
```

If you want finer control over the disposition of the elements use a grid layout.

If you really want to use "absolute coordinates" then you must always remember to pass the parent widget, otherwise children widgets will not have a place to draw themselves.

Comment: Hello again @Bakuriu! The code worked fantastically and now I understand what went wrong big time. Thank you so much! I just have a quick question if you don't mind. I need to be able to change labels of this widget during and after creation. Also, I need to access clickEvent. Do I need to get into signals/slots? What way would you suggest me to go with? What do you think I should do?

Comment: I am super happy. ;-) Ha ha. xD

Comment: @Phil To change label you can use the `setText` method of the `QLineEdit`. If for `clickEvent` you mean when the user clicks the button, then yes: you can connect a function to the `QPushButton.clicked` signal. For example: `self.btn.clicked.connect(the_callback)`.

Comment: Super awesome. Thanks a lot Bakuriu.